# Wordpress click and search with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem with implementing my working script into my website. The local self-made script works perfectly. It uses jQuery autocomplete. When I type in 3 letters it will display the results. When I click on the results it will auto search.

I am trying to implement this into my current search box but I can't get it to work. In my local file I get the answers from an array but in my Wordpress version am using Ajax request to get the answers.

I am not sure which arguments to use in my WordPress function. Who can help me?

#### My working file:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="main.js"></script>
<title>Autocomplete</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="states">Geef een naam op:</label>
    <input id="states">
    <button id="go" style="display: none;" >GO</button>
    <div id="no-result" style="display: none;">State not found.</div>

    <p id="resultaten"></p>
    <script>
        function weergeven() {
        var x = document.getElementById("Medewerkers").value;
        document.getElementById("resultaten").innerHTML = x;


        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript

```
$("#states").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        btnGoClick();
    }
});

$(function () {

    var stateList = [{
        "value": "Jurre"
    }, {
        "value": "hans"
    }, {
        "value": "Roy"
    }, {
        "value": "lars"
    }, {
        "value": "Ewald"
    }, {
        "value": "Remy"
    }, {
        "value": "Marvin"
    }, {
        "value": "Niek"
    }, {
        "value": "Arnold"
    }];

    $("#states").autocomplete({
        source: stateList,
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            btnGoClick(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});



function btnGoClick(value) {
    document.getElementById("resultaten").innerHTML = value;
}
```

#### Where it need to work:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.autocompl').autoComplete({
        source: function(name, response) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'private link',
                data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });         
        },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log("Hij doet het");

        }

    });
}); 

function btnGoClick() {
    console.log("Hij doet het")
}

</script>
```

Nothing is showing up on my console, no error or console.log

Who can Help me?

#### Edit: Here is the response code:

```
var wpAjax = jQuery.extend( {
    unserialize: function( s ) {
        var r = {}, q, pp, i, p;
        if ( !s ) { return r; }
        q = s.split('?'); if ( q[1] ) { s = q[1]; }
        pp = s.split('&');
        for ( i in pp ) {
            if ( jQuery.isFunction(pp.hasOwnProperty) && !pp.hasOwnProperty(i) ) { continue; }
            p = pp[i].split('=');
            r[p[0]] = p[1];
        }
        return r;
    },
    parseAjaxResponse: function( x, r, e ) { // 1 = good, 0 = strange (bad data?), -1 = you lack permission
        var parsed = {}, re = jQuery('#' + r).empty(), err = '';

        if ( x && typeof x == 'object' && x.getElementsByTagName('wp_ajax') ) {
            parsed.responses = [];
            parsed.errors = false;
            jQuery('response', x).each( function() {
                var th = jQuery(this), child = jQuery(this.firstChild), response;
                response = { action: th.attr('action'), what: child.get(0).nodeName, id: child.attr('id'), oldId: child.attr('old_id'), position: child.attr('position') };
                response.data = jQuery( 'response_data', child ).text();
                response.supplemental = {};
                if ( !jQuery( 'supplemental', child ).children().each( function() {
                    response.supplemental[this.nodeName] = jQuery(this).text();
                } ).length ) { response.supplemental = false; }
                response.errors = [];
                if ( !jQuery('wp_error', child).each( function() {
                    var code = jQuery(this).attr('code'), anError, errorData, formField;
                    anError = { code: code, message: this.firstChild.nodeValue, data: false };
                    errorData = jQuery('wp_error_data[code="' + code + '"]', x);
                    if ( errorData ) { anError.data = errorData.get(); }
                    formField = jQuery( 'form-field', errorData ).text();
                    if ( formField ) { code = formField; }
                    if ( e ) { wpAjax.invalidateForm( jQuery('#' + e + ' :input[name="' + code + '"]' ).parents('.form-field:first') ); }
                    err += '<p>' + anError.message + '</p>';
                    response.errors.push( anError );
                    parsed.errors = true;
                } ).length ) { response.errors = false; }
                parsed.responses.push( response );
            } );
            if ( err.length ) { re.html( '<div class="error">' + err + '</div>' ); }
            return parsed;
        }
        if ( isNaN(x) ) { return !re.html('<div class="error"><p>' + x + '</p></div>'); }
        x = parseInt(x,10);
        if ( -1 == x ) { return !re.html('<div class="error"><p>' + wpAjax.noPerm + '</p></div>'); }
        else if ( 0 === x ) { return !re.html('<div class="error"><p>' + wpAjax.broken  + '</p></div>'); }
        return true;
    },
    invalidateForm: function ( selector ) {
        return jQuery( selector ).addClass( 'form-invalid' ).find('input').one( 'change wp-check-valid-field', function() { jQuery(this).closest('.form-invalid').removeClass( 'form-invalid' ); } );
    },
    validateForm: function( selector ) {
        selector = jQuery( selector );
        return !wpAjax.invalidateForm( selector.find('.form-required').filter( function() { return jQuery('input:visible', this).val() === ''; } ) ).length;
    }
}, wpAjax || { noPerm: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.', broken: 'An unidentified error has occurred.' } );

// Basic form validation
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $('form.validate').submit( function() { return wpAjax.validateForm( $(this) ); } );
});
```

Comment: Can you output the response and see what you get/don't get?

Comment: Does it help if you use `keyup` instead of `keypress`?

Comment: Hi, this is what I get: https://pastebin.com/7GbDqiEH

Comment: This tutorial might help you https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-to-load-search-results/

Comment: add also an `error: function(xhr,err){console.error(xhr,err)}` method to your ajax object and see what you get in the console.

Comment: @jeff It look a bit to complex to me

Comment: @jeff also , after integrating the error method , you should show us the WordPress function that takes care of the response

Comment: @AnatoliiBivol I added the error method and it didn't result into anything

Comment: @ThomSchraa - that tutorial may look complex because the problem is complex.  Additionally, the URL that you have hidden from us matters a lot - there's a special way to get an AJAX url in WordPress (see [using AJAX in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)) - lastly, you should check your "network" panel in your developer tools.  It will show you TONS of useful information about the AJAX request - what was sent, where it was sent, the response type (200, 404, etc), and the response information.

Comment: @cale_b I already looked into the chrome network panel, the response is: ["Jurre"] and the preview is ["Jurre"] 0:"Jurre"  .

Comment: @ThomSchraa show us the php/WP function that takes care of the response

Comment: @ThomSchraa - you need to include these details in your question.  AJAX is complicated - without the PHP function you're using, and the results from the network tab (which you have shared in the comment above), it's difficult to help.  Your response is not valid JSON, BTW, so it's not going to be useful to your javascript.  At this point we need to see your PHP function so we can help you figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @cale_b        I added the respons script.

Comment: @ThomSchraa - not that. We need the php function that hooks to the ajax action you are setting. Also what is your `url: 'private link'` - we need just the last part of it. It should be a special link for wordpress ajaxUrl. Maybe you should really read more about ajax and WP.